# RESTful interfaces in Django

Tags: django, rest

I'm willing to build a restful service using Django, I'm coming form RoR background and facing some problems that could be defined using the following questions:

1. What package do you recommend to use to have RESTful interfaces?
2. Is there a way to make nested resources like a post HTTP request to  /posts/post_id/comments that adds a new comment ?
3. Is there a way to add some extra actions out of the CRUD set, like having extra method called `notify` on `Post` resource that works on post HTTP request.

Cheers,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Check out django piston.
2) Yes, you set it up in your urls list.
3) Yes, this is straightforward to do in your view.

Django Piston:
http://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you can do a *lot* just by implementing your own views that present theirselfs in a RESTful way.

But, there is a project called [piston](http://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home) that seems to be exactly what you're looking for: "A mini-framework for Django for creating RESTful APIs".